# CSS not being applied to its assigned class

Tags: html, css

Trying to apply a few lines of css to 4 `<p>` for them to be displayed in 4 columns or a grid format, what I've written for this works on another website I've made but doesn't seem to be applying here and I don't know what I'm missing here. essentially wanting to have 4 columns to display 4 product types, for a college project.

I defined the 4 product types in tiers `bronze`, `silver`, `gold` and `platinum`, with this code,

```css
body {
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, "sans-serif";
     background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
 #navbar-container {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 100%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
 .navbar {
     list-style-type: none;
     overflow: hidden;
     display: flex;
     float: right;
     padding: 1%;
     margin: 1%;
     font-size: 16px;
}
 li a {
     background-color: #47B9B4;
     border: 0;
     border-radius: 56px;
     color: #fff;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: inline-block;
     font-family: system-ui,-apple-system,system-ui,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Ubuntu,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
     font-size: 18px;
     font-weight: 600;
     outline: 0;
     padding: 16px 28px;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     transition: all .3s;
     user-select: none;
}
 li a:before {
     background-color: initial;
     border-radius: 125px;
     content: "";
     height: 50%;
     left: 4%;
     opacity: .5;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     transition: all .3s;
     width: 92%;
}
 li a:hover {
     box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 0 3px 15px inset, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0 3px 5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0 10px 13px;
     transform: scale(1.05);
}
 #main-content {
     display: flex;
}
 .advert1 {
     background:#BEBEBE;
     border-radius: 5px;
     padding-right: 10px;
     padding-left: 10px;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     text-align: center;
     width: 47%;
}
 .advert2 {
     background:#BEBEBE;
     border-radius: 5px;
     padding-right: 10px;
     padding-left: 10px;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     text-align: center;
     width: 20%;
}
 p span {
     background: white;
}
 .button {
     margin-right: 20px;
}
 .main-content {
}
 .main-pic {
     display: block;
     width: 1100px;
     height: 700px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
}
 .footer{
     background:#BEBEBE;
     padding:0px 0px;
     font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
     text-align:center;
}
 .footer .row{
     width:100%;
     margin:1% 0%;
     padding:0.6% 0%;
     color:gray;
     font-size:0.8em;
}
 .footer .row a{
     text-decoration:none;
     color:white;
     transition:0.5s;
}
 .footer .row a:hover{
     color:#fff;
}
 .footer .row ul{
     width:100%;
}
 .footer .row ul li{
     display:inline-block;
     margin:0px 30px;
}
 .footer .row a i{
     font-size:2em;
     margin:0% 1%;
}
 @media (max-width:720px){
     .footer{
         text-align:left;
         padding:5%;
    }
     .footer .row ul li{
         display:block;
         margin:10px 0px;
         text-align:left;
    }
     .footer .row a i{
         margin:0% 3%;
    }

.product-info {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
     margin-top: 8%;
     text-align: center;
     }
.bronze{
     display: flex;
     text-align: center;
     margin-left: 64%;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: 260px;
     border: 5px solid black;
     border-radius: 25px;
     background-color: black;
     color: #356300;
}
 .silver {
     display: flex;
     text-align: center;
     margin-left: 50%;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: 370px;
     border: 5px solid black;
     border-radius: 25px;
     background-color: black;
     color: #356300;
}
 .gold {
     display: flex;
     text-align: center;
     margin-left: 35%;
     margin-right: 100px;
     width: 350px;
     border: 5px solid black;
     border-radius: 25px;
     background-color: black;
     color: #356300;
}
 .platinum {
     display: flex;
     text-align: center;
     margin-left: 35%;
     margin-right: 100px;
     width: 350px;
     border: 5px solid black;
     border-radius: 25px;
     background-color: black;
     color: #356300;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div id="navbar-container">
        <nav>
          <a href="index.html">
            <img src="../../materials/Logo.png" alt="CoreTech Logo" width="350" height="120">
          </a>
          <ul class="navbar">
            <li>
              <a class="button" href="index.html">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="button" href="services.html">Price plans</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="button" href="products.html">Resources</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="button" href="contact us.html">Support</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="button" href="why coretech.html">Why CoreTech</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
      
    <div class="ad-container">
      <p class="advert2">Products prices plans and services</p>
    </div>
      <div id="main-content">
         <div class="product-info">
             <p class="bronze"> text here
             </p>
             <p class="silver"> text here
             </p>
             <p class="gold"> text here 
             </p>
             <p class="platinum"> text here
             </p>
         </div>
      </div>

    <footer>
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="row">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="contact us.html">Contact us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="services.html">Our Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Terms [&] Conditions</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Career</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row"> vinnies Copyright © 2023 Vinnie - All rights reserved || Designed By: vinnie </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Expecting the tiers to be in a row with a background applied.
If there is a better way to achieve the same effect please educate me, thanks in advance.

Comment: You specified `background-color: black` and `color: #356300` for all 4 of them. What else do you expect?

Comment: All your class colors are the same so you'll get what is expected from those.

Comment: Sorry for some reason it runs as expected here but not in dreamweaver

Comment: You have put them under a media query.

Answer (score 0):

Set the "background-color" to the color you are intending (platinum, gold, etc...). The "color" property defines the text color, not the background.

Comment: Appreciate that but when i run the snippet here its displaying the "tiers" in a row as desired but in Dreamweaver this isn't happening for some reason.